# disable notification in facebook comments plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-comments, facebook-social-plugins

Im dealing with a major problem with the fluent work of facebook comments.

I have implemented as needed the plugin into my Wordpress site: 
http://www.elimatana.co.il/recommendations/

However many users addressed me that for every new comment that it is posted on that page - **the previous people who commented receiving a facebook notification**.

I have tried several solutions with zero results. I would like to know if this is a known problem or if there is one what is the common solution to the matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Facebook bug. Sadly other than an acceptance of the bug by Facebook back in November 2012, there has been no update.

See here for more information, and Subscribe to the bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/306791559425667?browse=external_tasks_search_results_5224554e42ac64619196232